# Create files from multiple files contents

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to create new files with the names created by data from lines in several files.

I want to read all lines of just the .txt files in a folder and then create files from that list.

The files are have various amounts of lines and there could be a various amount of .txt files.

Here is the code that I have tried;

```
    static void WriteToFile(string directory, string name)
    {
        string filename = String.Format(name);
        string path = Path.Combine(directory, filename);
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Inserted Text");
        }
    }
```

......

```
    string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt");
    foreach (string file in allFiles)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
        foreach (string newfile in lines)
        {
            WriteToFile(folder, newfile);
        }
    }
```

This is now creating the files but I need to specify the extension as they are just created as 'file1' instead of 'file1.ext'

Comment: not sure, new to c# so not sure how to catch exceptions properly. it doesn't carry on with the rest of the script anyway.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: OK, so I have got the above code to work however I need to be able to specify the extension it gives to the files it creates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void WriteToFile(string directory, string name)
{
    string filename = String.Format(name + ".ini");
    string path = Path.Combine(directory, filename);
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Inserted Text");
    }
}
```

......

```
var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt");
foreach (string file in allFiles)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
    foreach (string newfile in lines)
    {
        WriteToFile(folder, newfile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[File.Create Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) returns `FileStream`. The `FileStream` **must be disposed to flush file**. Try using this code to create an empty file:

```
File.Create(fileName).Dispose();
```

Also, take a look at the similar question: [Creating an empty file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802541/creating-an-empty-file-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

Without any details of error/exception, to me it seems either permission issue, or character issue.
You can use `Path.GetInvalidPathChars` with `Enumerable.Intersect`  to check if file path contains invalid characters before creating new file

```
char[] invalidPathChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
foreach (string newfile in lines)
    {
        if (invalidPathChars.Intersect(newfile).Any())
        {
          Console.WriteLine(newfile + " contains invalid characters for file name");
          continue;
        }
        File.Create(newfile);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`File.Create` returns a `filestream` that you can use to write to the new file. But you are not providing the path that is the argument in `Create` but the line. The line might be an invalid path.

You can use  this query instead:

```
string invalidCharacters = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
var allPaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.txt")
    .SelectMany(path => File.ReadLines(path))
    .Select(line => { 
        string fileName = line;
        foreach (Char c in invalidCharacters)
            fileName = fileName.Replace(c.ToString(), "_");
        return new{ line, path = Path.Combine(targetFolder, fileName) };
    } );
foreach(var p in allPaths)
{
    File.WriteAllText(p.path, p.line);
}
```

Edit: however, that will very likely result in this error:

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.

So you need to use a method that shortens the path (f.e. using a logic that appends a number to avoid duplicate names).