# Writing a CSV log file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a Winforms program that needs to log data points into a `.CSV` file. It's fairly simple, date/time and a double (the data), and go to the next line.

Here's what I have so far (not working, I get an error saying the file is busy/already open - however, it's empty)

```
if (!Directory.Exists(SavePath.Text + "\\LOG"))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(SavePath.Text + "\\LOG");

string LogFileName = SavePath.Text + "\\LOG\\Seeing-Log-" + TimeNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".csv";

if (!File.Exists(LogFileName))
    File.Create(LogFileName);

string LogString = TimeNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-_HH-mm-ss") + "," + FWHM_Value.ToString("F:");
File.AppendAllText(LogFileName, LogString + Environment.NewLine);
```

It's that last line that generates the error.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

thanks
Steve

Comment: I didn't copy the exact error message but it says the file is busy / already open. Of course, nothing else is accessing it. The program actually creates if it doesn't exist. That part is working.

Comment: you forgot to close the file

Comment: hmmm. The exemple I found (on MSDN I think) didn't call anything to close the file, or save it for that matter. I'll look into it, thanks

Answer (score 6):

[`File.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an open [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) to the file that's just been created. Either change your code to work with `FileStream` in both the non-existent and existent file cases, or just close the file after creating it:

```
if (!File.Exists(LogFileName))
  File.Create(LogFileName).Close();
```

But, of course, if you check the documentation for [`AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Appends the specified stringto the file, creating the file if it does not already exist.

You'll realise that the above two lines are completely redundant anyway and can be removed:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(SavePath.Text + "\\LOG"))
  Directory.CreateDirectory(SavePath.Text + "\\LOG");
string LogString = TimeNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-_HH-mm-ss") + "," + FWHM_Value.ToString("F:");
File.AppendAllText(LogFileName, LogString + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can even use the free looging tools. Here is one 'log4net'

You can also write the csv file using this. I am assuming currently you are not using logging tool. it will work for you without any code for implementation .

http://element533.blogspot.in/2010/05/writing-to-csv-using-log4net.html

Have a great day!!

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
File.Create(LogFileName);
```

with

```
File.Create(LogFileName).Close();
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802541/creating-an-empty-file-in-c-sharp) to create empty file.

Answer (score 0):

The file is locked when you create it. Just update your code to this:

```
                File.Create(LogFileName).Close();
```