# How to generate the Log File at End of the program Execution

Tags: c#

I have Developed a console application (using C# and oracle) which will read some data from the Database generate a Excel sheet and send the mail to respective Address.  In my  application I generate a log file and put log in every steps. When my application start running it is creating the Log file and start writing the Log. And my Log file Name is Like:

```
 logFileName = "XYZ"+ "_" + System.DateTime.Today.Date.Day.ToString() + "." + System.DateTime.Today.Date.Month.ToString() + "." + System.DateTime.Today.Date.Year.ToString() + "" + System.DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString()+ ".txt";
```

This file is generate onetime  in a hour and every Execution it is just override the Data. But now I want to generate separate log file for Each Execution of program. If I am trying to add in file name (min,sec) and start writing log file every sec it is generating a new log file  in middle of program execution. So I want to Write Total log in End of the program execution or any error encounter to terminate the program. So where should i store the initial log data and finally i need to write it.

I know there are some relevant post but i did not find the relevant to my concern. Please help me out to find the solution.

Comment: do you open, write and flush the log file ervery time a log entry is created? please share your log function

Comment: Use a logging library like NLog or log4net. They already provide log rollover by date, time, log size, number of events etc

Answer (score 1):

You can do logging by hand, but I would recommend a logging library like NLOG, which supports your scenario out of the box and is well tested.

http://nlog-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

Add the hour to the end of the file name. That will create the new file.

You can also try File.Create:

[Creating an empty file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802541/creating-an-empty-file-in-c-sharp)

```
using (File.Create(filename)) ;
```

EDIT: You can also just use a stringbuilder to build up the log data, then write to a file at the end.

Comment: can you please Enplane your ans how to add the  timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I would use logging tool like log4net and do the configuration to create log file on each execution

check [log4net one file per run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048844/log4net-one-file-per-run) and [Log4Net basics with a Console Application (c#)](http://geekswithblogs.net/MarkPearl/archive/2012/01/30/log4net-basics-with-a-console-application-c.aspx)

Comment: @user1666620: how to use stringbuilder to achieve that . Can you able to put some code format.It will help me.

Comment: Hi I tryed your link  Log4Net basics with a Console Application (c#) but it is not generating any log file.

Comment: how should i provide my file path dynamically in  Log4Net basics with a Console Application (c#). because it is hard codded it app.config