# File.Create queries

Tags: c#, file, io

I recently came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802541/creating-an-empty-file-in-c-sharp) where the marked answer is by Jon Skeet.
In it he explains the different ways of creating an empty file such as:

```
using (File.Create(filename)) ;

using (File.Create(filename)) {}

File.Create(filename).Dispose();
```

and then there is also another way that people recommend using:

```
File.Create(filename).Close();
```

Now Jon's answer goes in to some detail about which one to use and why etc. But the answer is outdated/old and there isn't as much detail as I'd like about which one would be better for ensuring the file is closed and why.

Comment: I kind of like one of the other answers, using `File.WriteAllText` with an empty string.  It may be *slightly* less efficient under the hood, but it leaves the disposal to the framework code rather than needing to be called explicitly or through any kind of trickery.  (If I saw that `using` block approach in production code it might require a double-take to fully grok it.  Might be slightly more efficient, but such double-takes can lead to misunderstandings of the code's behavior and future bugs.)

Comment: Yeah that's the main reason for asking this because I have found that code in a legacy project and was researching it. However I myself find the WriteAllText method in this instance to be more confusing.

Comment: Jon's best suggestion is wrapping the whole thing in an aptly named method.  Run performance tests, race condition tests, etc. all after the fact to tweak down to the byte as needed (if needed at all).  But as long as the functionality exists in one abstracted place with a good name then the rest of the production code which uses it will be clear and understandable.

Comment: I suppose but was mainly wondering about the actual functionality of each because it's all well and good having it in a method. But if that fails every time we're back to square one just with less code to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer most definitely is not outdated. You could have checked with a little research into the actual implementation of the `FileStream.Dispose` method in the publicly available reference [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,1302), that the `Dispose` method of a `FileStream` will perform a call to `handle.Dispose`, and perform a number of other actions.

The `FileStream` class does not override the implementation of the virtual [`Stream.Close()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,240) method, implemented in its base class. This base class will currently just call the virtual `Dispose(true)`, and thus leads to the same path.

As mentioned in documentation on the [Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

> This method calls [Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx), specifying true to release all resources.
>   You do not have to specifically call the Close method. Instead, ensure
>   that every Stream object is properly disposed. You can declare Stream
>   objects within a using block (or Using block in Visual Basic) to
>   ensure that the stream and all of its resources are disposed, or you
>   can explicitly call the Dispose method.

Nevertheless, you always should call `Dispose`<sup>**1**</sup> when you are working with an `IDisposable` instance, as it could (now or at some time in the future) hold other internal resources besides the file handle, that would **not** be released if you only called `Close` on the `FileStream` instance.

That being said, a static file creation method such as `File.WriteAllBytes` or `File.WriteAllText` that ensures proper disposal would also work. But - in my opinion - these feel awkward and do not express intent that well.

Wrapping this in a static method called `CreateEmptyFile`, or a static class `EmptyFile` with a single method `Create` as suggested in the original answer makes it explicit what your intention is.

<sup>**1**</sup> This should be understood as either a direct call to `Dispose` or (preferably) by wrapping the resource in a `using` block.

Comment: I understand this but is there not always a chance that the Dispose call will not get called? So should one always use a using in this case? However odd it may look?

Comment: In my opinion, if you request a disposable instance by calling a method on some class, you are responsible for calling `Dispose` on it.

Comment: Responsible yes, but is there not a chance that the self called dispose will not actually be called? Say for example in a threaded situation?

Comment: How could anything thread related interfere in a call like `using(File.Create("abc.ext"));` ?

Comment: That's what I'm saying would you not do that rather than .Dispose? or was I misunderstanding what you was saying?

Comment: This should not really make a difference. An exception thrown from the call to `Create` would not return an instance to be disposed. But in general, due to preference and habit, when dealing with `IDisposable`, I prefer to go with a `using` block.

Comment: Same here, I don't think I made myself clear or I didn't understand you but either way glad we agree on that. And thanks for the additional comments and help.